# UITable load first UITableViewCell for my last row of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While coding with UITableView, I encounter this bug that I couldn't understand. I got 3 rows for my table and setting 50px for each row, except the 2nd row that I set it 500px which fill the whole screen. Problem comes when I scroll down to bottom, my bottom role is repeating first row appearance.This is my custom code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TestTable";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if (indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row==0) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }       
        if (indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row==1) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        if (indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row==2) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }


    }
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        return 400;
    }
    return 50; 
}
```

According to the code, first row is red color, second role is red and third one is blue. But my last row is red color (repeating the first row). If I set my 2nd row to shorter than the screen, e.g. 100px, third row loading fine.

Original Display

[image]

After Scroll Down

[image]

Appreciate for all kind of advice, as I am running out of ideas how is this happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 2nd row is long first row becomes invisible and its cell is reused in last row. That's why you should configure cell each time `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called i.e. after if `(cell == nil) {...}` block:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TestTable";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row==0) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }       
    if (indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row==1) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    if (indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row==2) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hoha. I thought my method can save cell initialization, but didn't realize it was a big mistake of mine. Appreciate your explanation.